# $\int_{\lambda} |f(z)| dz=0$ if $f$ is a function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a function holomorphic in a simply-connected region G is true that for any curve closed $\lambda$ in $G$ is $\int_{\lambda} |f(z)| dz=0$?

Hi, I wanted to consult their opinion with regard to the previous question, I consider it to be a question of care. I think the answer is true, my problem is that still can not prove it nor I found a cotraejemplo, I have only come to inequality that tells me $\int_{\lambda}|f(z)| dz \ge 0$

Comment: Notice that $|f(z)| \geq 0$.  What can you say about a positive function that integrates to zero on a set of positive measure?

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Note the presence of $dz$, which is a complex-valued path element.

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_{\lambda } |f(z)|\,dz = \int |f(z(t))|\,z'(t)\,dt$ can positive, negative, zero, or any complex number. This is because the "velocity" $z'(t)$, the factor coming from parametrization of the curve $\lambda$, is complex-valued.

For example, if $\lambda$ is the circle of radius $1$ centered at $1$, then $\int_\lambda |z|\,dz = 4i$, [as computed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/517107/). It follows that when $\lambda$ is the circle of radius $1$ centered at $e^{i\theta}$, the integral  $\int_\lambda |z|\,dz $ is $4ie^{i\theta}$.